# extremely high Cook's D & dfbetas results from influence.ME

Tags: r, diagnostics

I fit a mixed effects logistic regression with the glmer function from the lme4 package to some data I have. Next, I've been using the influence.ME package to run some diagnostics (e.g. Cook's D and dfbetas). However, I'm getting extremely high values for both Cook's D and dfbetas. I don't know what is the most likely cause of these results. I haven't been able to find anything on this yet.

In my study, subjects are assigned to one of two conditions (iv1) and then make binary decisions for trials of a task where a stimulus varies (within-subject) continuously (iv2). They also all complete a self-report measure (mv1). Here's a small set of sample data:

```
dat <- structure(list(subject = c(71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 
71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 73, 
73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
73, 73, 73, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 
74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 
75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 
76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 77, 
77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 
77, 77, 77, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 
78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 
79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 
80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 81, 
81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 
81, 81, 81, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 
82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 
83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 
84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 85, 
85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 
85, 85, 85, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 
86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 
87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 
88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 89, 
89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 
89, 89, 89, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 
90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 
91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 
92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 93, 
93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 
93, 93, 93, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 
94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 
95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 
96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 97, 
97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 
97, 97, 97, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 
98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 
99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 
101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 
102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 
102, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 
103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 104, 104, 
104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 
104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 
105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 106, 
106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 
106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 
107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 
108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 
108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 
109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 
109, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 
110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 
111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 
111, 111, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 
112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 113, 113, 113, 113, 
113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 
113, 113, 113), iv2 = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 
0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 
0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 
0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 
0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 
0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 
0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 
0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 
0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 
0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 
0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 
0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 
0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 
0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 
0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 
0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 
0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 
0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 
0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 
0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 
0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 
0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 
0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 
0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 
0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 
0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 
0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 
0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 
0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 
0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 
0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 
0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 
0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 
0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 
0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 
0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 
0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 
0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 
0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 
0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5), iv1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), dv = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), mv1 = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.7, 
0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 
0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 
0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4)), .Names = c("subject", 
"iv2", "iv1", "dv", "mv1"), row.names = c(1461L, 1462L, 1463L, 
1464L, 1465L, 1466L, 1467L, 1468L, 1469L, 1470L, 1471L, 1472L, 
1473L, 1474L, 1475L, 1476L, 1477L, 1478L, 1479L, 1480L, 1481L, 
1482L, 1483L, 1484L, 1485L, 1486L, 1487L, 1488L, 1489L, 1490L, 
1491L, 1492L, 1493L, 1494L, 1495L, 1496L, 1497L, 1498L, 1499L, 
1500L, 1501L, 1502L, 1503L, 1504L, 1505L, 1506L, 1507L, 1508L, 
1509L, 1510L, 1511L, 1512L, 1513L, 1514L, 1515L, 1516L, 1517L, 
1518L, 1519L, 1520L, 1521L, 1522L, 1523L, 1524L, 1525L, 1526L, 
1527L, 1528L, 1529L, 1530L, 1531L, 1532L, 1533L, 1534L, 1535L, 
1536L, 1537L, 1538L, 1539L, 1540L, 1541L, 1542L, 1543L, 1544L, 
1545L, 1546L, 1547L, 1548L, 1549L, 1550L, 1551L, 1552L, 1553L, 
1554L, 1555L, 1556L, 1557L, 1558L, 1559L, 1560L, 1561L, 1562L, 
1563L, 1564L, 1565L, 1566L, 1567L, 1568L, 1569L, 1570L, 1571L, 
1572L, 1573L, 1574L, 1575L, 1576L, 1577L, 1578L, 1579L, 1580L, 
1581L, 1582L, 1583L, 1584L, 1585L, 1586L, 1587L, 1588L, 1589L, 
1590L, 1591L, 1592L, 1593L, 1594L, 1595L, 1596L, 1597L, 1598L, 
1599L, 1600L, 1601L, 1602L, 1603L, 1604L, 1605L, 1606L, 1607L, 
1608L, 1609L, 1610L, 1611L, 1612L, 1613L, 1614L, 1615L, 1616L, 
1617L, 1618L, 1619L, 1620L, 1621L, 1622L, 1623L, 1624L, 1625L, 
1626L, 1627L, 1628L, 1629L, 1630L, 1631L, 1632L, 1633L, 1634L, 
1635L, 1636L, 1637L, 1638L, 1639L, 1640L, 1641L, 1642L, 1643L, 
1644L, 1645L, 1646L, 1647L, 1648L, 1649L, 1650L, 1651L, 1652L, 
1653L, 1654L, 1655L, 1656L, 1657L, 1658L, 1659L, 1660L, 1661L, 
1662L, 1663L, 1664L, 1665L, 1666L, 1667L, 1668L, 1669L, 1670L, 
1671L, 1672L, 1673L, 1674L, 1675L, 1676L, 1677L, 1678L, 1679L, 
1680L, 1681L, 1682L, 1683L, 1684L, 1685L, 1686L, 1687L, 1688L, 
1689L, 1690L, 1691L, 1692L, 1693L, 1694L, 1695L, 1696L, 1697L, 
1698L, 1699L, 1700L, 1701L, 1702L, 1703L, 1704L, 1705L, 1706L, 
1707L, 1708L, 1709L, 1710L, 1711L, 1712L, 1713L, 1714L, 1715L, 
1716L, 1717L, 1718L, 1719L, 1720L, 1721L, 1722L, 1723L, 1724L, 
1725L, 1726L, 1727L, 1728L, 1729L, 1730L, 1731L, 1732L, 1733L, 
1734L, 1735L, 1736L, 1737L, 1738L, 1739L, 1740L, 1741L, 1742L, 
1743L, 1744L, 1745L, 1746L, 1747L, 1748L, 1749L, 1750L, 1751L, 
1752L, 1753L, 1754L, 1755L, 1756L, 1757L, 1758L, 1759L, 1760L, 
1761L, 1762L, 1763L, 1764L, 1765L, 1766L, 1767L, 1768L, 1769L, 
1770L, 1771L, 1772L, 1773L, 1774L, 1775L, 1776L, 1777L, 1778L, 
1779L, 1780L, 1781L, 1782L, 1783L, 1784L, 1785L, 1786L, 1787L, 
1788L, 1789L, 1790L, 1791L, 1792L, 1793L, 1794L, 1795L, 1796L, 
1797L, 1798L, 1799L, 1800L, 1801L, 1802L, 1803L, 1804L, 1805L, 
1806L, 1807L, 1808L, 1809L, 1810L, 1811L, 1812L, 1813L, 1814L, 
1815L, 1816L, 1817L, 1818L, 1819L, 1820L, 1821L, 1822L, 1823L, 
1824L, 1825L, 1826L, 1827L, 1828L, 1829L, 1830L, 1831L, 1832L, 
1833L, 1834L, 1835L, 1836L, 1837L, 1838L, 1839L, 1840L, 1841L, 
1842L, 1843L, 1844L, 1845L, 1846L, 1847L, 1848L, 1849L, 1850L, 
1851L, 1852L, 1853L, 1854L, 1855L, 1856L, 1857L, 1858L, 1859L, 
1860L, 1861L, 1862L, 1863L, 1864L, 1865L, 1866L, 1867L, 1868L, 
1869L, 1870L, 1871L, 1872L, 1873L, 1874L, 1875L, 1876L, 1877L, 
1878L, 1879L, 1880L, 1881L, 1882L, 1883L, 1884L, 1885L, 1886L, 
1887L, 1888L, 1889L, 1890L, 1891L, 1892L, 1893L, 1894L, 1895L, 
1896L, 1897L, 1898L, 1899L, 1900L, 1901L, 1902L, 1903L, 1904L, 
1905L, 1906L, 1907L, 1908L, 1909L, 1910L, 1911L, 1912L, 1913L, 
1914L, 1915L, 1916L, 1917L, 1918L, 1919L, 1920L, 1921L, 1922L, 
1923L, 1924L, 1925L, 1926L, 1927L, 1928L, 1929L, 1930L, 1931L, 
1932L, 1933L, 1934L, 1935L, 1936L, 1937L, 1938L, 1939L, 1940L, 
1941L, 1942L, 1943L, 1944L, 1945L, 1946L, 1947L, 1948L, 1949L, 
1950L, 1951L, 1952L, 1953L, 1954L, 1955L, 1956L, 1957L, 1958L, 
1959L, 1960L, 1961L, 1962L, 1963L, 1964L, 1965L, 1966L, 1967L, 
1968L, 1969L, 1970L, 1971L, 1972L, 1973L, 1974L, 1975L, 1976L, 
1977L, 1978L, 1979L, 1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 
1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 
1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 
2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2041L, 
2042L, 2043L, 2044L, 2045L, 2046L, 2047L, 2048L, 2049L, 2050L, 
2051L, 2052L, 2053L, 2054L, 2055L, 2056L, 2057L, 2058L, 2059L, 
2060L, 2061L, 2062L, 2063L, 2064L, 2065L, 2066L, 2067L, 2068L, 
2069L, 2070L, 2071L, 2072L, 2073L, 2074L, 2075L, 2076L, 2077L, 
2078L, 2079L, 2080L, 2081L, 2082L, 2083L, 2084L, 2085L, 2086L, 
2087L, 2088L, 2089L, 2090L, 2091L, 2092L, 2093L, 2094L, 2095L, 
2096L, 2097L, 2098L, 2099L, 2100L, 2101L, 2102L, 2103L, 2104L, 
2105L, 2106L, 2107L, 2108L, 2109L, 2110L, 2111L, 2112L, 2113L, 
2114L, 2115L, 2116L, 2117L, 2118L, 2119L, 2120L, 2121L, 2122L, 
2123L, 2124L, 2125L, 2126L, 2127L, 2128L, 2129L, 2130L, 2131L, 
2132L, 2133L, 2134L, 2135L, 2136L, 2137L, 2138L, 2139L, 2140L, 
2141L, 2142L, 2143L, 2144L, 2145L, 2146L, 2147L, 2148L, 2149L, 
2150L, 2151L, 2152L, 2153L, 2154L, 2155L, 2156L, 2157L, 2158L, 
2159L, 2160L, 2161L, 2162L, 2163L, 2164L, 2165L, 2166L, 2167L, 
2168L, 2169L, 2170L, 2171L, 2172L, 2173L, 2174L, 2175L, 2176L, 
2177L, 2178L, 2179L, 2180L, 2181L, 2182L, 2183L, 2184L, 2185L, 
2186L, 2187L, 2188L, 2189L, 2190L, 2191L, 2192L, 2193L, 2194L, 
2195L, 2196L, 2197L, 2198L, 2199L, 2200L, 2201L, 2202L, 2203L, 
2204L, 2205L, 2206L, 2207L, 2208L, 2209L, 2210L, 2211L, 2212L, 
2213L, 2214L, 2215L, 2216L, 2217L, 2218L, 2219L, 2220L, 2221L, 
2222L, 2223L, 2224L, 2225L, 2226L, 2227L, 2228L, 2229L, 2230L, 
2231L, 2232L, 2233L, 2234L, 2235L, 2236L, 2237L, 2238L, 2239L, 
2240L, 2241L, 2242L, 2243L, 2244L, 2245L, 2246L, 2247L, 2248L, 
2249L, 2250L, 2251L, 2252L, 2253L, 2254L, 2255L, 2256L, 2257L, 
2258L, 2259L, 2260L, 2261L, 2262L, 2263L, 2264L, 2265L, 2266L, 
2267L, 2268L, 2269L, 2270L, 2271L, 2272L, 2273L, 2274L, 2275L, 
2276L, 2277L, 2278L, 2279L, 2280L, 2281L, 2282L, 2283L, 2284L, 
2285L, 2286L, 2287L, 2288L, 2289L, 2290L, 2291L, 2292L, 2293L, 
2294L, 2295L, 2296L, 2297L, 2298L, 2299L, 2300L, 2301L, 2302L, 
2303L, 2304L, 2305L, 2306L, 2307L, 2308L, 2309L, 2310L, 2311L, 
2312L, 2313L, 2314L, 2315L, 2316L, 2317L, 2318L, 2319L, 2320L, 
2341L, 2342L, 2343L, 2344L, 2345L, 2346L, 2347L, 2348L, 2349L, 
2350L, 2351L, 2352L, 2353L, 2354L, 2355L, 2356L, 2357L, 2358L, 
2359L, 2360L), class = "data.frame")
```

The model looks like this:

```
require(lme4); require(influence.ME)

mod <- glmer(dv ~ iv1*iv2*mv1 + (1 | subject), data = dat, family="binomial", 
             glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=100000)))

# Get Cook's D
mod_infl <- influence(mod, group="subject")
cooks.distance(mod_infl, sort = T)
```

This example shows one Cook's D over 40,000,000! Is it a problem with my model? It doesn't seem like this is caused by a small sample size because fitting the model to subsets of the actual data don't produce such extreme values.

Comment: it's going to be extremely hard to answer this question without a [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000); the link gives some suggestions for creating a MWE without exposing your data ...

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the helpful link. I've edited my post to contain some sample data that produces at least one extremely high Cook's D. My actual dataset is larger and produces a greater number of extreme values.